# Unknown SSL protocol in login to Adobe Connect

Tags: php

I am making login to Adobe connect. I've sending http-request like this

```
$ch = curl_init('https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=nurgasemetey@gmail.com&password=D742455B61/');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_exec($ch);
$info= curl_getinfo($ch);
echo 'passed' . $info['total_time'] . ' secconds ' . $info['url'] . '------ and http-code'. $info['http_code'];
print curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And I receive such response;

```
passed0.328 secconds https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=nurgasemetey@gmail.com&password=D742455B61/------ and http-code0
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to emea2cps.adobeconnect.com:443
```

How can I solve this problem?

curl-version:7.29
php-version: 5.4.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I didn't add the following

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```